# Get only values from the array of array using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I got an array from database as

```
[
  {id:
     {unitno: 'abc'},
   amount: 100},
  {id:
     {unitno: 'xyz'},
   amount: 150}
]
```

Now my required answer is that should be in the following format,

```
[["abc",100],
 ["xyz",150]]
```

But after some coding I got an array of Array as shown below in the console

```
[0:[0:"abc",1:100]
 1:[0:"xyz",1:150]]
```

Before question down / marking duplicate please read my requirement, and if its there then mark it and please post that link as per my required solution so i can get my solution from there

So any help will be great help....

Comment: yours one is not a valid json

Comment: Yep, not valid.

Comment: i am editing my question please check it once

Comment: `[0:[0:"abc",1:1]1:[0:"xyz",1:2]]`is not a valid array in JS or JSON so you cannot manipulate. Where does that data come from? If you get it as a string I guess you could massage the data a bit into a format that works.

Comment: @GillesC, I have edited the question please do have a look at it once

Comment: Could I ask, why the unusual format?

Comment: @CallumLinington, for highcharts donut I need it in that format.

Comment: Ahhh yes, they are a pain!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
data = [
 {id:
    {unitno: 'abc'},
  amount: 100},
 {id:
   {unitno: 'xyz'},
  amount: 150}
]

var array =[]
data.forEach(function(item){
  var tmpArray = []
  tmpArray.push(item.id.unitno,item.amount)
  array.push(tmpArray)
})
```

Now you will get your required  data in the array.

Comment: I have written the same coding. Getting indexes in console as shown in the question.

Comment: @G.Mounika please post a screenshot, or show some coding what you are doing. Array should not show indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you got this below code, but that's invalid Array

> `[0:[0:"abc",1:100]  1:[0:"xyz",1:150]]`

For your desired output you can do it with JavaScript, no need angular. Just run a simple `for` loop.

```js
var temp1 = [{
  id: {
    unitno: 'abc'
  },
  amount: 100
}, {
  id: {
    unitno: 'xyz'
  },
  amount: 150
}];
var eee = [];
temp1.forEach(function(el) {
  eee.push([el.id.unitno, el.amount])
});
console.log('eee:', eee);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you needed.

```
var arr = [{
    id : { unitno: 'abc' },
  amount: 100
},{
    id : { unitno: 'xyz' },
  amount: 150
}];

var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var newArray = [];
    newArray.push( arr[i]["id"]["unitno"] );
    newArray.push( arr[i]["amount"] );    
    result.push( newArray );    
}

console.log( result );
```

[image]